# Drupal role permissions not working

Tags: drupal, permissions

I have 2 different roles with exactly the same permissions and text formats when I switch a user between these two roles with the first one I can edit one specific node but not with the second, is there something I'm missing? I basically want to make these two roles to work exactly the same and after that I will add/remove some permissions.

I even tried using the direct edit URL "node/XXXXXX/edit" with no success on my 2nd role, as soon as i swap to the 1st role I can access the edit page.

On the content type I looked on the User Permissions and both of them are checked on the "Roles that can EDIT any content of this type"

As suggested on one of the answers I re created the role and cleared the cache but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Do both roles have the right permissions to work with the text format?

/admin/config/content/formats

or go to Configuration > Content authoring > Text formats

Comment: Thanks for answering Yes, they do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the second role;

- Create again and
- Clean cache.

That happened to me time ago.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I created a new role and set the same permissions, I checked the Text formats and they are all the same